# Errors on apt-get update

Tags: apt, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I am getting few errors when I run the command sudo apt-get update
here is the output of errors only.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources   404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found
Fetched 2,457B in 5min 5s (8B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/source/Sources.gz Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/quickly/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/quickly/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**I added the quickly-ppa but I cant find it in the sources list and getting error.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ppa.launchpad.net/quickly/ppa/ubuntu/dists -> there's no maverick version

http://ppa.launchpad.net/nanny/ppa/ubuntu/dists -> there's no maverick version

To fix this:

- `Applications > Sofware Center`,
- `Edit > Sofware sources...`,
- Enter your password,
- Go to the 'Other Software' tab, and
- Edit the PPAs for Quickly and Nanny so the 'Distribution' field is 'karmic'.

Also, there's a hash sum mismatch for the maverick-security repo (can be caused by corrupted downloads, etc.), which should be fixed by simply running `apt-get update` again.

Comment: Thanks htorque, it was helpful, but still I have a doubt why there is maverick in the ppa if there is no ppa for it? My maverick-security repo is showing error since the day one of installation on my two computers, so what could be the problem? thanks.

Comment: When you use apt-add to add the PPA, it will automatically use the distribution value of the Ubuntu version you currently use. About the hash sum mismatch - no idea, sorry.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, if you could please delete your answer so that this question will redirect - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run **`sudo apt-get update`** in terminal and then try reinstalling the package again.

Comment: I am not trying to install anything, Its just that, I am getting errors on apt-get update. I have mentioned the quickly ppa because it is showing errors and I cant find it in the sources list to delete it. Of course I got these errors after doing sudo apt-get update as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, if you could please delete your answer so that this question will redirect - thanks!